# Performing multiplication on isolated arraylist elements

Tags: java, algorithm, math, arraylist, multiplication

I am looking for a clear explanation to my question (NOT looking for code), but if a bit of code helps to explain yourself, then please do.. thank you :)

Question:

-using Java

-Main class asks user for 2 integer inputs, then places them into 2 arraylists, of type integer. Each digit is broken up and stored in its own index, so it is its own "element", so to speak.

For example, with my code right now, it goes something like this:

"Please enter an integer:"

688

"Please enter another integer:"

34

At this point now, internally, I have stored the input as 2 arraylists, that look like this:

ArrayList1: [6, 8, 8]

ArrayList2: [3, 4]

Now, lets say I want to perform some mutliplication, such as ArrayList1 * ArrayList2.

I'll probably go ahead and create a temporary 'result' arraylist, then move that answer over to arraylist1 when my calculation is complete.

But the part I am having trouble with, is coming up with a systematic clear way to multiply the arraylists together. Keep in mind that this example uses an arraylist which represents an integer of length 3 and 2, respectively, but this could be anything. I could, for example, have an arraylist with 50 elements, such as [2, 4, 4, 3, 7, 3, 6, 3,.............] which could represent a huge number in the trillions, etc.

Comment: `BigInteger` might be a more effective way to do this, if it's allowed/available/relevant.

Comment: Fair enough.  Wasn't sure if it was an exercise or not, from the context.

Comment: You would find it significantly easier if your lists were [8,8,6] and [4,3] such that the value represented is the sum of the element multiplied by ten to the power of its index - otherwise either you have to calculate in advance the number of digits in the result, or have to shift everything if you need another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudo code:

```
subtotal=0
iterate AL1 on index i (where i goes from zero to AL1.length()-1)
{
  iterate AL2 on index j (where j goes from zero to AL2.length()-1))
  {
    increment subtotal by AL2[AL2.length-j]*10^j * AL1[AL1.length-i]*10^i
    increment j
  }
  increment i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use a fast algorithm such as [Karatsuba multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_multiplication), the algorithm to multiply two numbers as you described is the simple O(n^2) algorithm that you learned in elementary school - multiply each digit of the second list by each digit of the first list, carrying as necessary.  So, for your first example, this algorithm gives you 688 x 34 = [6*4, 8*4, 8*4] + [6*3, 8*3, 8*3, 0] = [24, 32, 32] + [18, 24, 24, 0], which after carrying becomes
[2, 7, 5, 2] + [2, 0, 6, 4, 0] = [2, 3, 3, 9, 2].

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to ultimately multiply, in your example: 688 * 34. To do this with the structure that you are using, ArrayList it would be done using 2 for loops, one for each list (enhanced for loop since its an iterable object). Taking each element from the first array would be multiplied by 10^i power, giving you (8 * 10^0) + (8 *10^1) + (6 * 10^2) = 688. Each will be multiplied by each integer in the second list and multiplied by 10^j as was done in the first loop. Keep a running counter of each iteration through the loop to sum each multiplication as they happen.